# fork() and wait() / values changed by parent/child

Tags: c, fork, process, wait

If I have the following code (from Silberschatz, Operating Systems), why becomes value = 0 in Line P? I thought the parent process waits until the child is finished, and the child sets value = 5.

Can someone explan this to me?

```
int value = 0;
void *runner(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid,NULL);
        printf("CHILD: value= %d \n",value); /* LINE C */
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("PARENT: value= %d \n",value); /* LINE P */
    }
}

void *runner(void *param) {
    value = 5;
    pthread_exit (0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fork, you create a completely new process with a *copy* of the memory from the parent. (The OS might use tricks to make this fast, but the semantics remain.)

The parent doesn't see the changes done to variables in the child - they're separate processes with separate memory.

Threads, on the other hand, share the same memory area. So the change in the thread that ran `runner` is visible to the child's main thread.